# MS Graph returning undefined response

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, microsoft-graph, typescript

I am trying to get an image of a user with the help of MS Graph.

However, a response is always undefined and there is no error given but If I run a query on MS Graph Explorer I get the full image of a user. My query looks like `/users/xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com/photo/$value`.

```
 this.props.context.msGraphClientFactory.getClient().then(async(client:MSGraphClient): Promise<void> => {
         client.api('/users/'+ this.props.people[i].email+ '/photo/$value').get(async(error, response, rawResponse?: any) => {
            console.log(response);
            let picture = btoa(response);
            .... etc
            ...
          });
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `id` or `userPrincipalName` of a user to get the user photo. like:

`/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/photo/$value`.

You can check full documentation at: [Get the photo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0#get-the-photo).

**Additional documentation**

[Consume the Microsoft Graph in the SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aad-tutorial)

Comment: Yes, I know that you need to use userPrincipalName or id. My principal name is the same as email, so I am assuming I should get a response that is not undefined since the exact same query works on MS Graph Explorer?